# Is there any C/C++ editor in Linux that shows errors while typing

Tags: c++, c, linux, text-editor

The Visual C++ editor has a great feature which is that it underlines errors with a red line while typing the code. So for example, if you are using a variable that is not declared, it will underline it with a red curly line. In this way, the programmer can resolve a lot of errors while typing and doesn't have to wait for compiling for noticing them.

Now my question is, is there any editor for Linux that has this great feature?

Comment: I've heard of that eclipse IDE for C/C++ has the feature. However I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I think Netbeans can do that too. However, not just an editor :)

Comment: If you like emacs, you could try to have a look at this http://flymake.sourceforge.net/

Comment: try QTCreator(it is an IDE not an editor), it does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Kdevelop4 has some features you requested.
For example, it will underline undeclared variables with yellow and underline files that cannot be found with red. But in my opinion currently it yields in this functionality to MSVS2010.

Comment: @Cody. Well, Kdevelop4 does. I've just wrote my subjective opinion. In case the author uses Visual Studio it could help.

Answer (score 3):

`Vim` has a plugin, called [`c.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213). It enables *syntax checking* for C and C++.
You can read more about it in the [support file](http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-doc/csupport.html) and [this tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/tutorial-make-vim-as-your-cc-ide-using-cvim-plugin/).

I think this is the closest thing I know to what you want, using an *`editor`*.
If instead, by editor you include IDEs then, `Netbeans` and `Eclise` offer that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on using a "simple" editor, I can only recommend [Clang Complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302) for vim.

The plugin uses Clang under the hood to provide real-time feedback on errors, plus auto-completion.

You need to download/install Clang separately.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, you can use [ClangComplete](https://github.com/pfultz2/ClangComplete) for sublime text 3. It provides diagnostics, auto-completion, and navigation(such as goto definition), and it integrates well with CMake(although it doesn't require CMake).